# Why is "grep keyword" causing the terminal to stand by forever?

Tags: grep

When I type "grep doc" in the terminal, it just don't do anything, stopping the terminal from doing anything else before I escape using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd>.

I know this isn't how I'm supposed to use grep, but just curious why this is happening.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`grep` by default searches standard input if no files are given:

> grep searches the named input FILEs (or standard input if no files are
>   named, or if a single hyphen-minus (-) is given as file name) for
>   lines containing a match to the given PATTERN. By default, grep prints
>   the matching lines.

If you just do `grep doc` grep expects standard input to come and search inside it (don't enter parts between `<` and `>` into the terminal, these are comments):

```
$ grep doc
a b c <PRESS ENTER HERE>
doc <NO MATCH WAS FOUND IN PREVIOUS LINE, TYPE doc AND PRESS ENTER AGAIN>
doc <MATCH WAS FOUND>
```

Comment: OP can also press Ctrl+D on a line by itself to end the grep "session."

Comment: Good answer.  Just wanted to note that pretty much no one ever needs to use grep by typing like that, but it allows you to pipe standard output from a previous command, which *is* very useful.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt: It's actually a convenient way to debug complicated regexps.  You can run something like `grep '([a-z]+[0-9]*.x){2,3}'` and type a bunch of sample lines on your keyboard to make sure it matches what you think it does.  Lines that match will be echoed, lines that don't will not.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Thanks for giving a practical example for this! I'd always looked at null-arg invocations of things like grep and cat as being mainly theoretical.

Comment: @labyrinth They're not theoretical at all, they're used all the time when piping, e.g. `somecommand | grep foo`

Answer (score 15):

`grep` is waiting for input.

From `man grep`:

```
[...]
DESCRIPTION
       grep  searches  the named input FILEs (or standard input if no files are named
[...]
```